# Hook CreateProcess and inject a DLL in every child process

Tags: c, winapi, dll-injection

What I want to do: inject a DLL into a process in order to hook CreateProcess and monitor calls made from the victim process. When a call is made, I retrieve the child process ID and inject the same DLL into it. And so on.

I managed to do the first part: inject my DLL into a process, hook CreateProcess, monitor calls.

The hooking is pretty basic: over-write the first 5 bytes with a jmp to another function which looks like this:

```
__declspec(naked)
InterceptCreateProc()
{
    LPBYTE pJmpAdr;

    LPCTSTR lpApplicationName;
    LPTSTR lpCommandLine;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes;
    BOOL bInheritHandles;
    DWORD dwCreationFlags;
    LPVOID lpEnvironment;
    LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory;
    LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo;
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation;
    DWORD retv;

    void *inject;

    inject = (void* )Inject; // address of the function that should inject the DLL

    __asm
    {
        pop retv // return address
        // parameters
        pop lpApplicationName
        pop lpCommandLine
        pop lpProcessAttributes
        pop lpThreadAttributes
        pop bInheritHandles
        pop dwCreationFlags
        pop lpEnvironment
        pop lpCurrentDirectory
        pop lpStartupInfo
        pop lpProcessInformation
    };

    dwCreationFlags = dwCreationFlags | CREATE_SUSPENDED; // change creation flags to create suspended
    returnAdr = retv; // save the return address
    retv = (DWORD)inject; // redirect CreateProcess to return to the injection function
    g_procInfo = lpProcessInformation; 

    // push back all parameters on the stack
    __asm
    {
        push lpProcessInformation
        push lpStartupInfo
        push lpCurrentDirectory
        push lpEnvironment
        push dwCreationFlags
        push bInheritHandles
        push lpThreadAttributes
        push lpProcessAttributes
        push lpCommandLine
        push lpApplicationName
        push retv
    };

    // the bytes I have over written with my hook
    __asm
    {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
    };

    pJmpAdr = pOldFuncAdr + 5; // the point in CreateProcess where I should jump

    __asm
    {
        jmp pJmpAdr
    };
}
```

Now, the function that performs the injection:

```
__declspec(naked)
void
Inject()
{
    DWORD rValue;

    LPVOID baseAdr;

    HMODULE kernel32;

    FARPROC loadLib;

    HANDLE hThread;
    HANDLE hProc;

    __asm
    {
        mov rValue, eax // save the return value from CreateProcess
    };

    hProc = NULL;
    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
        0,
        g_procInfo->dwProcessId);
    if(NULL == hProc)
    {
        LogErrors("OpenProcess failed ",
            GetLastError());
    }

    baseAdr = NULL;
    baseAdr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc,
        0,
        strlen(dllPath) + 1,
        MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_READWRITE);
    if(NULL == baseAdr)
    {
        LogErrors("VirtualAllocEx failed ",
            GetLastError());
    }

    if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProc,
        baseAdr,
        dllPath,
        strlen(dllPath) + 1,
        0))
    {
        LogErrors("WriteProcessMemory failed ",
            GetLastError());
    }

    kernel32 = NULL;
    kernel32 = LoadLibrary(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));
    if(NULL == kernel32)
    {
        LogErrors("LoadLibrary faild ",
            GetLastError());
    }

    loadLib = NULL;
    loadLib = GetProcAddress(kernel32,
        "LoadLibraryA");
    if(NULL == loadLib)
    {
        LogErrors("GetProcAddress failed ",
            GetLastError());
    }

    hThread = NULL;
    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc,
        0,
        0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLib,
        baseAdr,
        0,
        0);

    if(NULL == hThread)
    {
        LogErrors("CreateRemoteThread failed ",
            GetLastError());
    }

    ResumeThread(g_procInfo->hThread);

    // I'm not sure if this is correct
    // it seems to be working -- CreateProcess returns a non zero value 
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, rValue // return value
        jmp returnAdr // return address
    }
}
```

Every time CreateProcess is called, Inject is called, but the only thing it does is to resume the main thread. The injection isn't happening for the child processes.

What are the big mistakes I made here?

EDIT: turns out that the above code is working and the problem was my test program.
Still, feedback is appreciated. What's good about what I did here? What's wrong?

EDIT2: And I found my first problem. Sometimes (quite often really), I get a Stack around variable startupInformation was corrupted. startupInformation is a STARTUPINFO struct which is a out parameter for CreateProcess. This is weird as I don't interact with startupInformation at all. The only things I change are the creation flags. processInformation has the right values even in the cases in which I get this error.

Comment: Would be much easier (not to mention more effective) to use `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: @David Heffernan I know, but that's no fun. Plus, I need to learn how to do it without SetWindowsHookEx.

Comment: Perhaps it is too early in the creation of the child process for injection to be successful?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I though about that, but if I don't suspend it, it crashes "sometimes". The problem here is that CreateProcess returns before the process is created. I suppose that even in this case the process information structure has correct information? Is there a way to know when a process is ready?